# Convert C5.0 model in R to Rpart Object to build fancyRpartPlot

Tags: r, graphviz, decision-tree, rules

I've build a C5.0 decesion Tree using package c50 in R. I want to visualize the tree in R. Instead of using plot function in R due to aesthetics, I perferd plotting tree using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273492/how-to-plot-visualize-a-c50-decision-tree-in-r).

Objective is to get probability of each class and the percentage of cases falling in that class at each node, which I can think can be done using fancyRpartplot. 
To do that I need the model to be an Rpart object. Can I convert C50 model to an Rpart object?

In case if it can not be done can I achieve this objective using graphviz solution which I am using or any other solution?

Comment: hey, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @stats555 No. Never got an answer to it. I used graphviz eventually.

Comment: @ Furqan Hashim : I posted a similar question over here, maybe you can check it out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68660559/r-converting-c50-models-to-rpart-models

Comment: What exactly did you do with "graphviz"? Are you talking about the "diagrammeR" library? You were able to make a decision tree in R using "graphviz"? Maybe you can post your code later - it would be great to check it out!

Comment: I am talking about Graphviz which is an open source graph visualisation software. You need to get that first for your desired platform. You can follow the blog here http://r-project-thanos.blogspot.com/2014/09/plot-c50-decision-trees-in-r.html which would guide on how to make the tree digram.