# Converting "C50 models" to "rpart" models

Tags: r, tree, data-visualization, decision-tree, rpart

Is there a way to use the `rpart.plot` library to plot objects that do not belong to `rpart` (used for making decision trees)?

For instance, here is the classic `rpart` and `rpart.plot` library in action:

```
#load libraries
    library(rpart)
    library(rpart.plot)

#load data
    data(iris)

#fit rpart model (i.e. decision tree)
    r = rpart(Species ~., data=iris)

#plot model
    rpart.plot(r)
```

[image]

**Problem:** I am working on a multi-class classification problem (like the example above - I just illustrated this with the famous "iris dataset") where "rpart" is taking too long to run (I waited 10 hours and the "rpart" code still did not run).

However, I found another library in R called "c50", which is able to instantaneously create a similar model:

```
#load library 
library(C50)

#run same model
tree_mod <- C5.0(x = iris[, -5], y = iris$Species, rules = TRUE)

#view model
summary(tree_mod)

plot(tree_mod)
```

[image]

**Question** : Is there anyway to use the "rpart.plot" library with objects from the "C50" library?

For example:

```
#my attempt
rpart.plot(tree_mod)

Error in rpart.plot(tree_mod) : Not an rpart object
```

**My idea:**  It is possible to extract the distinct rules using the "C50" library :

```
summary(tree_mod)

Rule 1: (50, lift 2.9)
    Petal.Length <= 1.9
    ->  class setosa  [0.981]

Rule 2: (48/1, lift 2.9)
    Petal.Length > 1.9
    Petal.Length <= 4.9
    Petal.Width <= 1.7
    ->  class versicolor  [0.960]

Rule 3: (46/1, lift 2.9)
    Petal.Width > 1.7
    ->  class virginica  [0.958]

Rule 4: (46/2, lift 2.8)
    Petal.Length > 4.9
    ->  class virginica  [0.938]
```

Similar rules can also be extracted from the "rpart" library:

```
 rpart.rules(r)

    Species  seto vers virg                                               
     setosa [1.00  .00  .00] when Petal.Length <  2.5                     
 versicolor [ .00  .91  .09] when Petal.Length >= 2.5 & Petal.Width <  1.8
  virginica [ .00  .02  .98] when Petal.Length >= 2.5 & Petal.Width >= 1.8
```

It it somehow possible to "reformat the rules" from the `C50` library in such a way that they become compatible with `rpart.plot`?